# FileSavePicker in Light theme on C# windows metro App

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, windows-store-apps

I was wondering how to change the theme of FileSavePicker on a metro app. I only found answer to this question for android and it didn't help so much. And I didn't find anything in msdn documentation.
So is it possible to change the theme of a FileSavePicker? Does it exist a method or property such as fileSavePicker.RequestedTheme() ?

Just for information I defined my application's theme in App.xaml :

```
<Application
    x:Class="ClientAirNavLight_WS.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ClientAirNavLight_WS"
    RequestedTheme="Light">

    <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

                <!-- 
                    Styles that define common aspects of the platform look and feel
                    Required by Visual Studio project and item templates
                 -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: I believe that the FileSavePicker uses the System Accent color. You may be able to change its color by digging around in the files. Have a look in StandardStyles.xaml. You might find something useful in there.

Comment: Well I didn't find where perform some changes to affect the FileSavePicker, but this file is quiet large, I may miss something.

Comment: It might not be in there. I haven't seen it yet either. Other than that I'm not sure what you could do, so good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FileSavePicker colours are defined by the user's theme preferences, not by your application. It cannot be modified by StandardStyles.xaml.

In order that your app can't try and impersonate a system dialog (like FileSavePicker) your application doesn't have access to those user preferences.